# Can i take a high voltage system and a high amp system and merge them?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electronics

Lets say i have a battery with 50A but a low voltage output and a 30,000V but with only a few amps cause it was converted for to the Voltage could i somehow create a system where the Voltage from one system connect to the amps in another and flow into another system to power it? This isn't for any project ir something im just studying this stuff and wish to know is it even possible what would be needed and how expensive

Comment: are you asking about a dc-dc converter? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC-to-DC_converter

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you connect them, the high voltage source will not be able to provide the 50A. If it could you would have 50A @ 30kV, i.e a 1.5 MW power souce!

The best you can hope for is the available current from the 30kV source, at the sum of the voltages. If the 30kV source can supply 1A, and the battery is 12V, then the result would be 1A at 30,012V.

Either way, if your 30kV supply is able to supply more than a few mA, make sure you don't touch its terminals or you may end up permanently unable to appreciate the experiment :-) Note that 1A at 30kV is guaranteed to kill you.